# Trying to get API results to display, not sure what I'm missing.

Tags: javascript, api

I'm just trying to work with an API and just display the results in the browser.

I installed the chrome extension to bypass the CORS issue for the sake of testing, so I "think" that's not the problem, but I can't get it to even log the result? Not sure what I'm missing?

I have a console.log(data) in the callback from the function to get the api, but nothing is showing up?

```js
const NAMEURL = "https://uzby.com/api.php"

// get data from api
function getDataFromApi(value, callback){
  const QUERY = {
    min:`${value}`,
    max:`${value}`
  }
  $.getJSON(NAMEURL, QUERY, callback)
}

function renderResult(result){
  return `${result}`;
}

// render results to page
function displayName(data){
  console.log(data);
  const results = renderResult(data);
  $('.nameResult').html(results);
}

// wait for user to submit
function watchSubmit() {
  $('.js-search-form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const queryTarget = $(event.currentTarget).find('#js-dropValue');
    const thisquery = queryTarget.val();
    getDataFromApi(thisquery, displayName);
  });
}
// running the watch submit function waiting for click
$(watchSubmit);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="CW-favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </header>
    <section role="main" id="main">
      <div class="titlerow">
        <h2>Tagline</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonrow">
        <form action="#" class="js-search-form">
          <label for="js-dropValue">Number of Letters
          <select name="js-dropValue" id="js-dropValue" >
            <option value="choose">choose the number of letters</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
          </select>
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Create my name!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="nameResult">
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the devtools & network tab?

Comment: Also, have you used breakpoints to see your programs flow?  Is it hitting all of your functions?  What are the arguments being passed?

Comment: I apologize this is all new to me.  In the devtools I was just looking the console for the log. I've never worked with breakpoints. 

I have the function (watchSubmit) that runs on submit that sends the value of the drop down to the api call function (getDataFromApi). then there is a callback function there that should be run (displayName) which should be receiving the data from the API but is not per my console.log.  

When I don't use the chrome extension to allow CORS the cross origin error actually shows that I'm creating the correct api String?

Comment: Try looking at the "Network" tab in Chrome devtools (two over from "Console" and see if you can find your api call in there

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see it runs, and actually shows the response, in the response tab correctly so it's working, but I'm just not grabbing it correctly apparently.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark this answered? @TimHutchison put me down the right path to see  I needed to send the request totally differently, how do I close this?

Comment: @Casey You should be able to answer the question yourself with the steps you took to resolve the problem and then accept that answer.  Make sure to follow the [SO Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for answering a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timHutchison gave me a big tip which helped me out. I ended up just using and XMLHTTPRequest instead to accomplish getting the data in.